# How should we use the law tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think [law](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) needs some attention.  The current tag wiki reads:

> Rules and regulations established in the Old Testament by God through Moses

However, the questions using this tag include:

- [Should Christians uphold unjust laws that are not overtly immoral?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2827/should-christians-uphold-unjust-laws-that-are-not-overtly-immoral)
- [Is breaking copyright law a sin?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/is-breaking-copyright-law-a-sin-closed)

And I think we've had several other questions about modern day laws, and even some Biblical "laws" that are not established in the Old Testament.

I think either we need to change the tag wiki to apply to *all* forms of laws, or we need multiple tags.

**Edit**:

I see at least three broad categories of laws:

- Mosaic law
- Other "laws" or commandments in the Bible

  This probably includes the Jewish ceremonial laws that were an extension of, but not explicitly mentioned in, the Mosaic law, and the generic "law" that Paul talks about in his (which may contain, but is not limited to Mosaic law)
- Modern civil law

Answer (score 2):

I agree.  If the tag is supposed to be about the Law of Moses, it should be called law-of-moses.  There are enough other "laws" that Christians could interact with or have questions about that this particular one needs its own category.

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely more than one thing going on here.

How about [mosaic-law](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mosaic-law) vs [governmnet-laws](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/governmnet-laws)?

**edit** done.

When questions come up that need canon law or whatever else we can add a tag. If government-laws is not the best name we can change out but at least they are split up.

Comment: I like government-laws since civil-laws is one division of US laws ([compared to criminal law](http://www.rbs2.com/cc.htm)).  "government" seems to cover all of that.  Another idea: what about [tag:modern-law]?

Comment: [Secular Law] would probably better strike the contrast you are looking for, and it's less crude; then leave religious law under a banner like [Abrahamic Law] or [Religious Law]. Either will capture one or the other sense of "law" as someone starts typing it. Then as use cases actually occur for species (Mosaic, Canonical, etc) of religious law those tags will occur.

Answer (score 1):

With Catholicism closed, [Canon law](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_INDEX.HTM) ought to be on topic too eh?

Comment: Yes certainly. As soon as a question about it shows up we can tag it with that.